# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, java-6

I know that this Exception told me that I'm trying to parse to int an empty string, but I cannot figure it out why it's empty. The problem is the JTextField tMax, even when I try some int number in it.
This is the code:

```
package AppPackage.panelsPackage;

        import java.awt.Toolkit;
        import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;
        import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
        import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
        import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;


        public class Panel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

            /** Creates new form EulerPanel */
            public Panel() {
                initComponents();
            }

          private void initComponents() {
              //components
              private javax.swing.JTextField tMax = new javax.swing.JTextField()
              //code
              tMaxEuler.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                    tMaxKeyTyped(evt);
                }
            });

          public String getTMax() {
        String tMaxString = tMax.getText();
        return tMaxString;
    }


public class OptionFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

       //code
       private void runBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       Panel panel1 = new Panel();
       String tMaxString = panel1.getTMaxEuler();
       int tMax = Integer.parseInt(tMaxString);
       int sample = tMax +3;

     public static void main(String args[]) {
          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new OptionFrameHSimulator().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

I can't understand why the JTextField tMax results empty, even if I write a number in it.
What is the problem?
```

Comment: Where is the code for `tMaxKeyTyped`?

Comment: are you sure this is your code? does it even compile? you are missing `;`  at `tMax = new javax...` also you can't use modifiers (private, public, ... ) inside methods `private javax.s...` !!

Comment: I wrote just the important code to understand the issue, I know this is not compiling. I can't write down all the code :D

Comment: The code is not comprehensible and lacking key pieces. This makes it rather difficult to provide help. Please review [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on examples.